# Seeking help identifying the right causal model for my research

Tags: causality, treatment-effect, heterogeneity

I am conducting a quasi-experimental research where the treatment is of varying intensity. For e.g., to investigate the impact of CEO's transgression on the stock market behavior (hypothetical; not my research), the treatment is *negative publicity*. However, this treatment could be a divorce, fraud, inappropriate comments, etc. Does it make sense to classify them under a single umbrella of negative publicity? In most of the articles on heterogeneous treatment effects, the premise is that the impact of an event is different for different treated units. However, in this case, the events (treatments) itself are of varying intensity. Is there any article that deals with a similar situation?

Comment: I would consider this a multi-category treatment rather than treatment effect heterogeneity from a single treatment. There are propensity score- and regression-based methods for estimating the effects of multi-category treatments if you have measured enough variables to adjust for confounding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It was very helpful!